# Why MSS clamping in iptables(-nft) seems to take no effect in nftables?

Tags: iptables, nftables, ppp

My pppoe client automatically adds an iptables rule `iptables -t mangle -o "$PPP_IFACE" --insert FORWARD 1 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1400:65495 -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu` from `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d`. However, this rule in nftables looks like

```
table ip mangle {
    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
        oifname "ppp0" meta l4proto tcp tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn # tcpmss match 1400:65495 counter packets 714 bytes 42388 tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu
    }
}
```

Why contents after tcpmss is commented and this rule seems to do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

- the rule set through `iptables-nft` is using [xtables kernel modules](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XTABLES.html) (here: [`xt_tcpmss`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TCPMSS.html) and [`xt_TCPMSS`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS.html)) through the *nftables* kernel API along a [compatibility layer API](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_COMPAT.html), even if *xtables* was initially intended for (legacy kernel API) *iptables*.

  Native *nftables* cannot use *xtables* kernel modules by design: whenever *xtables* is in use, it's not native anymore, and the userland `nft` command (or its API) deals only with native *nftables*. Use of *xtables* is reserved for the compatibility layer. So when displayed through *nft* any such unknown module is displayed commented out (but see later).
- the current version of `iptables-nft` wasn't yet able to translate automatically the *iptables* rule into native *nftables* rule (for this case) or there is no equivalent native *nftables* rule to translate to (eg: ponder the [`LED`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LED.html) target).

  Here `nft` sees there are *xtables* modules that aren't translatable by the common translation engine so considers this part as off limits and adds a comment on the untranslatable part, but still translates what it knowns about. The call to *xtables* modules can be seen with `--debug=netlink`:

  ```
  # nft -a --debug=netlink list ruleset
  ip mangle FORWARD 2
    [ meta load oifname => reg 1 ]
    [ cmp eq reg 1 0x30707070 0x00000000 ]
    [ meta load l4proto => reg 1 ]
    [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000006 ]
    [ match name tcp rev 0 ]
    [ match name tcpmss rev 0 ]
    [ counter pkts 0 bytes 0 ]
    [ target name TCPMSS rev 0 ]

  table ip mangle { # handle 167
    chain FORWARD { # handle 1
        type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
        oifname "ppp0" meta l4proto tcp tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn # tcpmss match 1400:65495 counter packets 0 bytes 0 tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu # handle 2
    }
  }
  ```

  above: `match` and `target` mean *xtables* modules. Since *nftables* uses about the same engine as *iptables-translate* in this regard, one could guess `-m tcpmss --mss 1400:65495` got an issue because that's the one which starts with a comment and isn't translated in the output, while the last part was translated. **Whatever `nft` displays back here is only for the display and mustn't be taken as the actual rules**.

  The actual rules are the bytecodes shown with `--debug=netlink` (plus non-visible parts for *xtables* specific data), so this bytecode is the proof that this rule *is* doing something. It's just not useful to native *nftables*.

### Native *nftables* version

For example most of OP's *iptables* rule can be natively translated:

```
# iptables-translate -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
nft add rule ip mangle FORWARD tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn counter tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu
```

While there's no automatic translation available currently for `-m tcpmss --mss` , the feature is [available](https://manpages.debian.org/nft.8#EXTENSION_HEADER_EXPRESSIONS): `tcp option maxseg size` which can be used either as an expression (the equivalent of the match `-m tcpmss --mss`) or with `set` as a statement (the equivalent of the target `-j TCPMSS`). Below would be the result of such translation (and might be in the future once the translation engine is improved):

```
nft add rule ip mangle FORWARD 'oifname ppp0 tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn tcp option maxseg size 1400-65495 counter tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu'
```

The second value 65495 is probably useless (one could just use `tcp option maxseg size >= 1400` instead).

---

### Note

`nft` and `iptables-nft` can be misleading when trying to abuse translations. For example using *iptables* `v1.8.7 (nf_tables)` and *nft* v1.0.0, one can get this:

```
# iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
# nft list ruleset | tee /tmp/mss.nft
table ip mangle {
    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
        meta l4proto tcp tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn counter packets 0 bytes 0 tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu
    }
  }
# nft flush ruleset
# nft -f /tmp/mss.nft
# iptables-save 
# Table `mangle' is incompatible, use 'nft' tool.
```

That's because while `nft` was able to translate the whole ruleset when displaying it, the initial compat ruleset was still including an *xtables* target in the bytecode (the same as seen above: `[ target name TCPMSS rev 0 ]`): `iptables-nft` didn't behave as `iptables-translate` and `nft`'s output hid the difference. Once run again through the `nft` command, the result is full native *nftables* with `tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu` instead of `-j TCMPSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu` . But the `iptables-save` command doesn't recognize the result anymore as *iptables*-translated code and can't translate it back into *iptables* format.

Don't dump blindly *iptables* rules using *nftables* to reload them with *nftables*, this can bite later if *iptables* is still needed.

Comment: Thank you! As the mtu of ppp0 is 1492, perhaps `oifname "ppp0" tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn tcp option maxseg size 1453-65495 counter tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu` (or the lower limit should be 1452? I am not sure) can be a better rule.

Comment: @StevenYang so if it worked, you're supposed to accept my answer to thank me. As for 1453 instead of 1400 it's as you prefer, but I reused the information available in your question where 1400 was used.